# Dynamically add form elements on button press which stay after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am creating a multi page form with PHP.

I am using JavaScript to allow the user to create new text fields.

```
function add() {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += '<input type="text"><br><br>';
}
```

As it is a multi page form the users have the option to go back to previous pages. The problem is that once the page is reloaded the extra text fields that have been added disappear. How would I go about keeping them on the page once the page is reloaded? Would I need to create a cookie to store the added form elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is store them in sessionStorage then bring them on page load.

```
function add() {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += '<input type="text"><br><br>';
    sessionStorage.inputBoxes = document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML;
}

window.load = function() {
   if (sessionStorage.inputBoxes) {
      document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = sessionStorage.inputBoxes;
   }
};
```

I did write a plugin http://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbformstate  that persists form state, not in terms of dynamic controls but in terms of keeping form entry state using session and local storage by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can use

`$('selector_area').append('your control tag');`

Answer (score 0):

When you add an element with Javascript, you're modifying the Document Object Model (DOM). Whatever you do to the DOM is discarded once the page is left. So, you're going to have to reload all your changes when the user goes back. You have many ways to do this, some are:

- Use HTML5's `SessionStorage` or `LocalStorage`, which persist until the user disposes of it (one way is to clear all browsing data);
- Instead of using Javascript directly, use a Form to call a PHP script which will store the changes in the Session or Cookie.

Comment: Please reply to @qakbar (Posting on his behalf): How can I create a PHP session that will keep all the fields including all the dynamic fields and the calculations for subtotal, VAT and total.